# How can I store data inside python?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a game in which the player works for a certain amount of money. But I'm running the code on a discord server which means that there will be multiple users? If I can get a unique ID for each user then how can I store information for each user?

This is some code I made that basically reflects my other one. How can I store money as well as returning money if they enter a username that's been used before.

```
def start():
        name = input("What is your name?")
        main()
def main():
        print('1. New Player')
        print('2. Work')
        answer = input()
        if answer == '1':
            start()
        if answer == '2':
            work()
    def work():
        print("You work for $100")
        money += 100
        main()
    main()
```

(Sorry if my question is too broad... ask any questions if want more details.)

Comment: What do you mean by "on a discord server"? Are you using discord.py to run a bot that has commands that let users play this game? None of the code you've shared suggests that. As for storing the data, you could use a global dictionary or as Campbell McDiarmid suggests, create a class.

Comment: Yes I am using discord.py. The reason I didn't reflect the other code is because it just complicates things. I used this example because I need help with this problem, not discord.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple suggestion would be to create a class that describes a player, their attributes and any functions associated with the player.  For example:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.money = 0
        self.items = []
        self.level = 1
        # Initialize other player attributes here

    def add_money(self, amount_added):
        self.money += amount_added

def main():
    player_1 = Player(id=1)
    player_1.add_money(100)
    player_2 = Player(id=2)
```

This is a very generic example, but defining a class for a player will allow you to easily create an object for which you can associate each player.  If you add 100 to player 1's money then that will be completely independent of player 2's money.  I suggest searching up tutorials/examples on classes and you'll get a feel!